# Hierarchic comment, parent-child relationship

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to make reddit-like comments for my website. I have this database structure(`MySql`):

```
parent_id | comment_id | comment
```

This is an example data that comes from database:

```
var data = [
    {comment_id: "1a", parent_id: "", comment: "11111"},
    {comment_id: "2a", parent_id: "1a", comment: "22222"},
    {comment_id: "3a", parent_id: "1a", comment: "33333"},
    {comment_id: "4a", parent_id: "3a", comment: "44444"},
    {comment_id: "5a", parent_id: "", comment: "55555"},
    {comment_id: "6a", parent_id: "5a", comment: "6666"},
]
// if parent_id == "", it's parent.
```

I need to make that list relation with it's childs. I did but I can't implement recursive, so parents are only scoping `first childs`.

My implementation:

```
function parse(arr) {

    var mothers = []

    //find mothers

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        //if parent_id == "" => it's mother.

        if(arr[i].parent_id == "") {
            arr[i].childs = [] // make it's childs
            mothers.push(arr[i])
            arr = _.without(arr, arr[i])
        }
    }

    var childs = arr

    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        var possibleChild = childs[i]

        var parent_id = possibleChild.parent_id

        for (var z = 0; z < mothers.length; z++) {
            var mother = mothers[z]

            if(mother.comment_id == parent_id){ // match it with mother
                mother.childs.push(possibleChild)
            }
        }
    }

    return mothers

}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you're having difficulty writing a recursive solution, or that you are trying to avoid recursion?

Comment: I am trying to make a recursive func.